# Importing Custom Classes in Java, working with Command Line

Tags: java, class, import, terminal, compilation

I wrote a few classes in the same folder, here is the hierarchy:

```
bookpirate/

-Window.java

-Navigator.java

-NavEventHandler.java
```

All files have **"package bookpirate;"** in the beginning

here is how i imported them:

**Navigator class:**

```
package bookpirate;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import bookpirate.NavEventHandler;

public class Navigator
{
    private JPanel panel;

    public JTextField page;

    public JButton pageBack;
    public JButton addBefore;
    public JButton addAfter;
    public JButton pageForward;
    public JButton removePage;
    public JButton undo;

    public JTextField getPage() { return page; }

    public JButton getPageBack() { return pageBack; }
    public JButton getAddBefore() { return addBefore; }
    public JButton getAddAfter() { return addAfter; }
    public JButton getPageForward() { return pageForward; }
    public JButton getRemovePage() { return removePage; }
    public JButton getUndo() { return undo; }

    public int nOfPages;
    public int getNOfPages() { return nOfPages; }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Navigator();
    }

    public Navigator()
    {
        setListeners();
        System.out.println("Created NavEventHandler");
    }

    private void setListeners()
    {
        NavEventHandler handler = new NavEventHandler(this);

        page.addActionListener(handler);

        pageBack.addActionListener(handler);
        addBefore.addActionListener(handler);
        addAfter.addActionListener(handler);
        pageForward.addActionListener(handler);
        removePage.addActionListener(handler);
        undo.addActionListener(handler);

    }
}
```

**NavEventHandler class:**

```
package bookpirate;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import bookpirate.Navigator;

public class NavEventHandler implements ActionListener
{
    Navigator navigator;
    public NavEventHandler(Navigator nav)
    {
        navigator = nav;
        System.out.println("Created NavEventHandler");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String string = "actionPerformed";
        //if(event.getSource() instanceof Navigator)
        //{
            if(event.getSource() == navigator.getPageBack()) 
            { string = "pageBack";}
            /*else if(event.getSource() == Navigator.getAddBefore()) 
            { string = "addBefore";}
            else if(event.getSource() == Navigator.getAddAfter())
            { string = "addAfter";}
            else if(event.getSource() == Navigator.getPageForward()) 
            { string = "pageForward";}
            else if(event.getSource() == Navigator.getRemovePage()) 
            { string = "removePage";}
            else if(event.getSource() == Navigator.getUndo()) 
            { string = "undo";}
            else if(event.getSource() == Navigator.getPage()) 
            { string = "page " + event.getActionCommand();}*/
            string += " gotSource";
        //}
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is what i get when i compile the NavEnventHandler:

```
C:\Users\...\bookpirate>javac NavEventHandler.java
NavEventHandler.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import bookpirate.Navigator;
                 ^
  symbol:   class Navigator
  location: package bookpirate
NavEventHandler.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Navigator navigator;
        ^
```

All that while i can compile them **together without errors**

```
C:\Users\Falangrater\Desktop\Files\Programming\bookpirate>javac NavEventHandler.java Navigator.java Window.java

C:\Users\Falangrater\Desktop\Files\Programming\bookpirate>
```

But i cannot run them, together or separately

```
C:\Users\Falangrater\Desktop\Files\Programming\bookpirate>java Window Navigator NavEventHandler
Error: Could not find or load main class Window

C:\Users\Falangrater\Desktop\Files\Programming\bookpirate>
```

I Have tried making a manifest.txt file

```
Main-Class: Window
```

i can't add a .mf to the file

I tried to be as succinct as possible

Comment: @maszter How do i use them without importing? I get  error: cannot find symbol, as you can see in the NavEventHandler code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the Problem:

I put the classes in the package bookpirate. therefore, i needed to be in the parent folder of bookpirate to run the program:

```
/Programming> java bookpirate/Window
```

or

```
/Programming> java bookpirate.Window
```

instead of:

```
/bookpirate> java Window
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import classes from the same package.
[Why don't I have to import a class I just made to use it in my main class? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152446/why-dont-i-have-to-import-a-class-i-just-made-to-use-it-in-my-main-class-java)

You don't have a main method in any of your classes, so you cannot run it this way.
More: [Can we execute a java program without a main() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173474/can-we-execute-a-java-program-without-a-main-method)

EDIT:
You just have to move to parent directory and call it like that:

`java bookpirate.Navigator` or `java bookpirate/Navigator`

Comment: They all have void main methods, i just did't include them for brevity (they are in full now i edited). It's all well and good that i don'y have to import them, but why then do  i get an error "cannot find symbol"?

Comment: you pasted the same class twice